# Convert 32 bit long hex to 6 digit number OTP

Tags: java, hash, md5, one-time-password

How do I conver the followint 32 bit HEX to 6 digit decimal?

MD5: 9d10f0693b9d8e6c32c33d1e9be377b5

I hashed certain field to get the above. However, I would need to generate 6 digit PIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(your md5 is not 32 bits long but 128 (32 hex characters * 4bits/char) but it's not plain relevant... sorry)

The pin will not hold the 128 bits information the hash contains, so you have to take a subpart of it.

I'll assume your hash is a standard java String.

if you need the pin as a 6 digits int :

```
int pin = hash.hashCode() % 1e6;
```

I let you check if this method comply with your "security" exigences :)
hope it helps!

Comment: why % 1e7? I have the same problem but I have to produce a specific 6 digits from that hash...Could you please help?

Comment: value % 1e7 is a modulo that will return the rest of the division by 10'000'000. The maximum result is now: 9'999'999.
If you want to generate a pin number (human readable as classic integers) that contains 6 digits, use a modulo 1e6